# Linking valgrind-HEAD for MAC OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, valgrind, osx-elcapitan

When I try to install Valgrind onto my Macbook Pro with El Capitan installed I get this warning:

```
$ brew install -HEAD valgrind
```

> Warning: valgrind-HEAD already installed, it's just not linked

I then try to link and get this Error:

```
$brew link valgrind
```

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD...
>
> Error: Could not symlink include/valgrind/callgrind.h
>
> /usr/local/include/valgrind is not writable.

I then try:

```
$chmod 755 /usr/local/include/valgrind
```

and rerun and receive the same error:

```
$brew link valgrind
```

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD...
>
> Error: Could not symlink include/valgrind/callgrind.h
>
> /usr/local/include/valgrind is not writable.

I try to use this command and receive this warning:

```
$brew doctor
```

> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
>
> Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these: valgrind

I receive this result when I type:

```
$ls -ld /usr/local/include/valgrind
```

> drwxr-xr-x  62 root  admin  2108 Feb 23 18:29 /usr/local/include/valgrind

I'm not sure how to make valgrind writable. I believe that is what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure *you* own the prefix, not `root`:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

After that `brew link valgrind` should work.

Comment: I get the same error, just a different symlink path.

Error: Could not symlink lib/valgrind/32bit-core-valgrind-s1.xml
/usr/local/lib/valgrind is not writable.